# Python imports in deployed/local packages

Tags: python, python-import

How can I write `import foo.bar` in `__init__.py` so it will load the system-wide version of `foo/bar.py` when run from most places, but will load the local version of `bar.py` when run from within `foo`'s source directory?

```
# foo/__init__.py

from foo.bar import baz
baz()
```

```
# foo/bar.py
def baz:
    print('Hello")
```

This will always load the site-wide version of `foo/bar.py`, and never the local version.

From examples of other packages I have installed on-site, imports should be done with `import foo.bar`. (examples `numba`, `pandas`, `scipy`), but I'm not sure how they manage to develop these libraries (perhaps they always use virtual environments).

I also tried:

```
# foo/__init__.py
try:
    from bar import baz
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from foo.bar import baz
baz()
```

This does work, but it is pretty verbose to repeat everywhere in the library, and it seems prone to name-clashes.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? is `bar` not a module in `foo`?  If it is, shouldn't the package init *always* load the local version?  Is this for development?

Comment: If for dev, could this be an x/y problem?  I've mostly seen developing against installed local copies inside a venv, so if you're working on foo your changes are instantly available within the venv, but the system version (residing somewhere else) is unchanged.

Comment: Right.  I use a program which depends on `foo`.  But sometimes I need to debug `foo`, so I throw `__init__.py` into a debugger, but it loads the site-wide files.

Comment: It could be an X/Y problem.  So the question might actually be:  How do you debug python projects when a site-wide version is installed on your system?   Perhaps venv is the answer, but it seems a bit heavy-handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm not sure how they manage to develop these libraries (perhaps they always use virtual environments)

Yes, I think 99% or so of python dev work uses virtualenvs.  They're really not too hard---you might want to have a look at something like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage them. There's also the [pep582](https://peps.python.org/pep-0582/) approach, but that hasn't yet made it.  However you can spin up a venv *really easily* these days:

```sh
cd path/to/project
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
# and then something like
pip install -e . # installs in editable mode
```

If you don't want to do this, you can still have an `__init__` which loads the right files, by using relative paths:

```py
# foo/__init__.py
from .bar import baz
```

...at the cost of not being able to evaluate the `__init__` in an editor.  But you can still run it locally without installing!  Just use:

```sh
python -m foo
```

from the dir above foo.  Likewise you can use

```sh
python -m foo.bar
```

To load and execute `foo/bar.py` (assuming it does anything).

Note that if you take the usual approach of installing your package in editable mode inside a virtualenv and then working there, there's no reason not to use the `foo.bar` approach---and you can evaluate stuff without worrying about what `.` means. Lots of people don't like relative paths for exactly that reason.

If you *do* need to evaluate bits of `foo/__init__.py`, first do the imports manually in your repl and then send only the lines you care about.

Comment: Good answer.  I'm working in a debian environment with static versions of all libraries for my dependencies, so I haven't been using `pip` at all.  I also haven't found any "obvious" ways of using my IDE to set up a `venv`.  This explanation help a lot

Comment: @Stewart presumably you used something to get your package into the system, though?  Did you write your own .deb?  You might want to use pip *even if* you use system installers, just for portability. (Or maybe you're using setup.py or a wheel, in which case pip will install it locally just fine, if you install system-wide without pip)

Comment: Indeed, I use `dpkg-buildpackage` which relies on `pybuild` and `setup.py` to build a `*.deb`

Comment: In that case an editable pip install for development should actually be straightforward.  BTW google 'python virtualenv YOUR_IDE' if you want to see the toolchain way to do it.  Most ides have pretty decent venv integration, which helps when you want to evaluate odd bits.  Although I very much think it's worth working it out on the shell first.